# find common in two out of three columns, summarize them in R

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, tidyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
    genus_sub <- structure(list(GutREF001.1_MDA_1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), GutREF001.1_MDA_2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GutREF001.1_MDA_3 = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GutREF001.2_MDA_1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GutREF001.2_MDA_2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), GutREF001.2_MDA_3 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    ID = c("Enterococcaceae (B; Firm)", "Oscillospiraceae (B; Firm)", 
    "Enterobacteriaceae (B; Prot)", "Helicobacteraceae (B; Prot)", 
    "Peptoniphilaceae (B; Firm)", "Flavobacteriaceae (B; Bact)", 
    "Methanobacteriaceae (A; Eury)", "Coriobacteriaceae (B; Acti)", 
    "Micrococcaceae (B; Acti)", "Lactobacillaceae (B; Firm)")), .Names = c("GutREF001.1_MDA_1", 
"GutREF001.1_MDA_2", "GutREF001.1_MDA_3", "GutREF001.2_MDA_1", 
"GutREF001.2_MDA_2", "GutREF001.2_MDA_3", "ID"), row.names = c("Enterococcaceae (B; Firm)", 
"Oscillospiraceae (B; Firm)", "Enterobacteriaceae (B; Prot)", 
"Helicobacteraceae (B; Prot)", "Peptoniphilaceae (B; Firm)", 
"Flavobacteriaceae (B; Bact)", "Methanobacteriaceae (A; Eury)", 
"Coriobacteriaceae (B; Acti)", "Micrococcaceae (B; Acti)", "Lactobacillaceae (B; Firm)"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Identical column names separated by MDA_1, MDA_2 and MDA_3 are triplicates (technical replicate samples) analysis needs to be done between three such such identical samples at a time

I would like to compute:

i. Consensus -  i.e is for each row, determine ID's that are present (value == 1) in 50% of the samples or at least 2 out of three in this case

ii. Sample_consensus_detected - From the above determined consensus set, find number of IDs present in individual sample of the triplicate

iii.  Sample_consensus_not_detected - From the above determined consensus set, find number of IDs not present in individual sample of the triplicate

iv. Replicate_not_in_consensus - Present in individual sample but absent in consensus

iv. summary_metric_1 - (ii / (ii + iii))

v. summary_metric_2 = (iv / (ii + iv))

I wrote the following code to start summarizing triplicate groups:

```
row.names(genus_sub) <- genus_table$ID
genus_sub$ID <- NULL

genus_sub %>% 
  gather(key, value) %>% 
  extract(key, c("sample_id", "rep"), "([[:alnum:]]+)_MDA_([[:alnum:]]+)") %>% 
  group_by(sample_id) %>% 
  summarize(sample_sum = sum(value))
```

but have not been able to determine a way to calculate consensus i.e sum values for rows where `ID` is present (==1) in two out of three columns. Any help is appreciated. Expected output is as follows:
[image: Expected output is as follows:]

Comment: Can you show us your desired output just so that your objective will be clearer?

Comment: Hi, I have added edits to the question to show expected outcome

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate consensus by melting the data like so (note this requires the data **before** you drop the ID column):

```
melted <- melt(genus_sub,id="ID")
melted$variable <- substr(melted$variable,1,nchar(as.character(melted$variable))-2)
melted %>%
  group_by(ID,variable) %>%
  summarize(value = sum(value)) %>%
  dcast(ID ~ variable, sum)
```

The substring function drops the counter in the column names (now the values of `variable` in the melted data table) so that you can group by `variable`. If you have examples where there are more than 9 samples to take consensus over you could replace it with a more elaborate `gsub`.

Output gives the ID and sum of ==1 in each column (so to get to binary consensus you'd want to convert 2 or 3 to 1 and have it be 0 otherwise.

```
                              ID GutREF001.1_MDA GutREF001.2_MDA
1    Coriobacteriaceae (B; Acti)               0               0
2   Enterobacteriaceae (B; Prot)               0               0
3      Enterococcaceae (B; Firm)               0               0
4    Flavobacteriaceae (B; Bact)               0               0
5    Helicobacteraceae (B; Prot)               0               0
6     Lactobacillaceae (B; Firm)               0               0
7  Methanobacteriaceae (A; Eury)               0               0
8       Micrococcaceae (B; Acti)               0               0
9     Oscillospiraceae (B; Firm)               3               3
10    Peptoniphilaceae (B; Firm)               0               0
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand your solution until group_by... However summarize just sums the values for a particular ID. It does not calculate consensus and further derived metrics from the updated question (even if I convert 2 or 3 to 1) Can you please elaborate or update your answer a little bit to get the output in the attached figure from the updated questions. Thanks!